# Launch error | There is a problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 2)

Tags: xcode, github, xcode10

I am currently working on a project through github. My local project is connected to the github project folder through folder reference.[Current File/Folder setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIA08.png)  There hasn't been a problem, but now I keep getting the error "There is a problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 2)." Before that, earlier today, I was receiving the error: "could not launch 'PROJECT NAME'. Internal error"

with the initial error ("could not launch 'PROJECT NAME'. Internal error") I attempted to fix the Schema configuration by following option B in this link (https://github.com/olilarkin/wdl-ol/issues/120). After attempting that I began receiving the later error ("There is a problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 2).")[posix_spawn Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKVDX.png)

please help. Thanks